# URL filtering with input MAC addresses

Tags: linux, iptables, openwrt

I need to implement URL filtering mechanism on OpenWrt. I have a list of URLs and a list of MAC addresses, and these MAC addresses shouldn't have access to given URLs. URLs should be inaccessible in browser in that case or forwarded to localhost.

MAC address owners are devices connected to OpenWrt router.

Is this possible to achieve with iptables?
I tried with different approaches using string matching and --mac-source, non of these works.

Comment: URLs work on a completely different level than the IP packets accessible through `iptables`. I recommend to google for "transparent proxy". You *will* need to use `iptables` to forward HTTP requests to the proxy, but not to inspect URLs.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Squid (transparent proxy) + Squirm (URL filter).